# Querying a table where the field contains any order of given text strings

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, database

I want to query a table as follows:

I have a field called "category" and my input match contains N separate words.  I want the query to match all rows that contain all N words, but in any order.

For example if the field category contains "hello good morning world", my input query can contain "hello morning" or "good" or "world hello" and all are matches to the query.

How do I formulate such an SQL expression?

Also it would be good if the query can be made case insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL you can use the [boolean fulltext search feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) to achieve this.  You can put a + in front of each term and then only results with all the terms, in any order, will be returned.  You will need to make sure the column containing the category field has a fulltext index specified on it for this to work.  Other database engines probably have similar features.  So for example you might do something like the following assuming there were a fulltext index over the category column...

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE MATCH (category) AGAINST ('+term1 +term2 +term3' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I would avoid using the "LIKE" operator as others have suggested you would have to worry about the headache of mixed upper/lower case and if you have a large database using a % in the front of a LIKE search term is going to cause a full table scan instead of using an index which is horrible for performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not writing the loop that will build this query for you. This will get the job done, but it will be pretty inefficient.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE (
    TOUPPER(category) LIKE '*HELLO*' AND
    TOUPPER(category) LIKE '*GOOD*' AND
    TOUPPER(category) LIKE '*MORNING*' AND
    TOUPPER(category) LIKE '*WORLD*'
    );
```

You could also research using REGEXes with SQL.